# How can I copy some part of jTable to another jTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a list persons (in a jTable) and want to export it to excel file I need each person go to separated sheet so I need split the original jTable, but I don't know how?

this is what I want to do?

```
public void exportToExcelSelectedPersons(HSSFWorkbook hwb, JTable table) {
        String sheetName = null;
        final PersonsList personList = PersonsList.getInstance();
        TimeTable tt = new TimeTable();

    tt = new TimeTable();
    int[] selectedIndexes = personList.getSelectedIndices();
    sheetName = personList.getModel().getElementAt(selectedIndexes[0]).getName();
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            if (table.getValueAt(i, j) instanceof PersonInfo) {
                break;
            }
            //copy table (for this specefic person) to tt
            //exportToExcel(hwb, tt, sheetName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can share [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) betweens two [JTables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) (for example by using [RowFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for 2nd. `JTable`)

or by copy data betweens `TableModels` by using separate two `TableModels` for two `JTables` by using `RowFilter` for 2nd. `JTable`

Answer (score 2):

Use a list of POJOs to store the data and write some simple TableModels wrapping the list to use it in JTables. Then pass this list of POJOs to the export method - not the JTable and not the TableModel.

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly mean, can you please explain more

Comment: Here's a sample (readonly) TableModel I wrote some time ago, which wraps a List: http://puces-samples.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/puces-samples/tags/sessionstate-1.0/sessionstate-suite/sessionstate-sample/src/blogspot/puce/sessionstate/sample/ParticipantTableModel.java?revision=13&view=markup (If you want it to be mutable make sure to call the fire methods of the base class.) The export method should not work on UI classes such as TableModel or JTable. It should take a List<MyObj> instead.